# Natron: how to resume a render that crashed

Tags: video

I'd like a way to restart a render when a render crashes in Natron, given that the output are written in separated files (using output `out_%05d.png`).

I don't want to change the first frame in my render because otherwise I could forget what is the actual first frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice solution (thanks Hank): just uncheck the "overwrite" parameter in the write parameter. That way, only non-existing files will be created.